# i am not able to see uploaded image from simple html and php code

Tags: php, html

i am making a simple image upload event or function from simple php and html code,although i dont get any errors, i cant see my uploaded image in my folder named 'uploads',what should i do?

....html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>prasad</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">upload</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
...html



...php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    print_r($file);
    echo "<br>";

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileType=$_FILES['file']['type'];
    $file_temp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_error=$_FILES['file']['error'];
    $file_size=$_FILES['file']['size'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png','pdf');


    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($file_error === 0) {
            if ($file_size<1000000){
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('',true).".".$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uplaods/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($file_temp_name, $fileDestination);
                header("Location: pp.php?success");

            }else {
                echo "this is too big file";
            }
            # code...
        }else{
            echo "there was an error ..!";
        }

    }else{
        echo "<h1>you couldnt choose any file..</h1>";
    }


}
```

the only error is , i aint able to see my uploaded image

Comment: I see your code: `$fileDestination = 'uplaods/'.$fileNameNew;`

Comment: You should check the return value from `move_uploaded_file()`

Comment: I saw that your code is perfect, it's working for me. Maybe your uploads folder path is incorrect, please check the folder path. Also I saw that in the form you used action="upload.php", is the file name is correct? Please check it again otherwise put the action as blank.

Comment: You probably don't have an existing folder named "uplaods". Perhaps yours is actually named "uploads"

Comment: @Phil , though i have  created the folder called 'uplaods', i cant see uploaded image,,plz note that i am using ubuntu 18.04 and not windows..